# Difference between pointer address

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, sizeof, stdvector

I'm testing some code using pointer arithmetic, but I don't understand in what format I get size. 
I assume `sizeof` give me size in units of machine word(size of char == 1 machine word), but in what units are the difference between pointer addresses returned?

I'm using VS2008 and x64 win7 and x64 compiler.

```
void test_pointer_delta()
{
    int sum=0;
    int n= 100000;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        char* p1= new char;
        char* p2= new char;
        sum += p2-p1;
    }
    double dp= (double)sum/n; //~64
    int sz= sizeof(char);//1
    int p_sz= sizeof(char*);//8
    printf("diff: %f \n",dp);
}
```

What is 64? 64 bits? (so word size on x64 system is 64 bits?)

**Edit:**
I want to use this "trick" to test how much memory used by vector,because it seems it is not frees all memory(according to task manager some little amount remains)
here is test code:

```
void test_containers()
{   
    int N=1000*1000;

    int temp= 10;
    clock_t t;

    //for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
    {
        t= clock();
        //vector
        std::vector<int> vec;
        for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
        {
            vec.push_back(temp);
        }
        t= clock()-t;
        printf("vec: %d tics , %f sec \n",t, ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        //clear vec
        t= clock();
        vec.clear(); //not frees memory of vector just makes size = 0
        std::vector<int>(vec).swap(vec); //swap trick frees memory
        t= clock()-t;
        printf("vec clear: %d tics , %f sec \n",t, ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        int c= vec.capacity();
        int sz= vec.size(); 
    }
}

    //assume dp1 should be the same as dp2
    char* p1 = new char;
    char* p2 = new char;
    int dp1= p2-p1;
    test_containers();
    char* p3= new char;
    int dp2= p3-p2;
```

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behavior. Subtracting two pointers is only meaningful when both point into the same array (in which case the difference is the distance between them, in the number of array elements).

Comment: The result of `new` is not predictable. `sum` could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you try this code you will get your answer:

```
char s[10];
char *p1 = &s[0];
char *p2 = &s[1];
std::cout << p2 - p1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of result of subtracting two pointer is: [std::ptrdiff_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t). Unit for the difference of two pointer T* is number of T Elements.